# Parameter Binding - Empty collection if one element fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action like this

```
   public ActionResult Collection(List<int> keywordIds)
   {
        //Do some stuff here
        return View();
   }
```

which works fine with a query string like this

```
/List?keywordIds=6&keywordIds=2&keywordIds=2
```

but if i have a url like

```
/List?keywordIds=6&keywordIds=2&keywordIds=2&keywordIds=All
```

it seems like if the value of one of the id's can't be be parsed to an int then i get an empty collection instead of just ignoring that one value.

Is there are way to ignore conversion issue? so i would expect to get a list with 3 int's in both cases

Comment: You can achieve this if you write your own model binder. In my opinion, it might be easier to just have a `List<string>` and try to convert the values in your controller... Alternatively, you could add a second parameter, just for the _All_  use case: `public ActionResult Collection(List<int> keywordIds, bool all = false)`. Then you could call `/List?keywordIds=6&keywordIds=2&keywordIds=2&all=true`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could do that.  That is have the same NVP to form an array. +1 TIL.